# Regex unmatch if followed by slash

Tags: regex

So I want to match a string that looks like this:
`apple/banana`

So my regex looks like `apple\s*/\\s*banana`
But I do not want to match if that is followed by slash like :
`apple/banana/` or `apple/banana /` but still will match if it is not directly followed by slash like `apple/banana juice/chocolate`

How do i achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Depends on your regex engine. See [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) and then [edit] in accordance with the guidance there.

Comment: What about `juice/apple/banana`?

Comment: Try to use [`^.+[^\/]$`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ0cbu/1)

Comment: @Ilyes `apple/banana juice/chocolate/` this matches.

Comment: @Ava The OP state _"**still will match** if it is not directly followed by slash"_

Comment: @Ilyes that is for `apple/banana juice/chocolate`.  All the matched examples the OP  has given has no slash at the end of the string.

Comment: @Ava [Nope](https://regex101.com/r/0bCBfM/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead to assert not a `/` preceded by optional whitespace chars excluding the newline.

```
\bapple/banana\b(?![^\S\r\n]*/)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bapple` Match apple preceded by a word boundary to not match for example pineapple
- `/` Match `/` (The forward slash does not need escaping the by itself is not used as a delimiter)
- `banana\b` Match `banana` followed by a word boundary to not match for example bananas
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is as the right is not

  - `[^\S\r\n]*/` Match 0+ whitspace chars excluding a newline and then match `/`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HPAo8F/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
\bapple\s*\/\s*banana\b(?!\s*\/)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/cTFcCm/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  apple                    'apple'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  banana                   'banana'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Of course ++, I totally forgot about the whitspace chars around the slash

Answer (score -1):

From your post, it seems like you do not want to match the string ending with `'/'`.

```regex
/^.+(?<!\/)$/gm
```

**Regex demo [here](https://regexr.com/5esf8).**

So how does this regex work?

1. `.+`

   This matches everything except line breaks.
2. `(?<!\/)`

   This is negated lookbehind assertion which checks at the end of the string there is no `'/'` character.
3. `^ ... $`

   Ensures to match from begining to end of the line.

Answer (score -1):

Would you please try the following:

```
^[^\/\n]+(?:\/[^\/\n]+)+$
```

Results:

```
apple                           no match
apple/banana                    match
apple/banana/                   no match
apple/banana /                  no match
apple/banana/mango              match
apple/banana/mango/             no match
apple/banana juice/chocolate    match
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ0cbu/3)